# What does "to smack of one of your gags" mean?

Tags: meaning

Here is the full sentence:

> This whole story is starting to smack of one of your gags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To "smack of" something is to taste or smell like something, to give someone an inkling that this thing that you're experiencing now is feeling suspiciously familiar (i.e. like one of that person's gags).

Comment: I think you should say that "this thing" is the story, not the gag; and the "flavor" of the story is such that the listener is becoming inclined to think that the story is actually a joke, or gag, that the storyteller is known to engage in occasionally.

Comment: @Hellion: Noted. I was in a hurry and didn't phrase it exactly right the first time. Thanks for pointing that out.